# Twitter Token not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I use Fabric, for login with Twitter, now i need send tweet without composer view, i used this code:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {

    TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] initWithUserID:session.userID];

    NSString *url = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
    NSMutableDictionary *message = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Test Text",@"status", nil];

    NSURLRequest *preparedRequest = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:url parameters:message error:&error];

    [client sendTwitterRequest:preparedRequest completion:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){

        if(!error){
            NSError *jsonError;
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonError];
            NSLog(@"%@", json);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }

    }];
}];
```

but always response with an error:

> Error: Error Domain=TWTRNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=, TWTRNetworkingStatusCode=401, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)}

the session is correct, but i can't understand how set token for request

Comment: What line is this error on? Set a debugger and check

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the error debugging

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm having a similar issue!